# Eigenvalue problem of a differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is known that $\sqrt z H^1_\nu(z)$ and $\sqrt z H^2_\nu(z)$ are two linearly independent solutions of the equation
$$-\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\chi+\Big(\frac{\nu^2-\frac{1}{4}}{z^2}\Big)\chi=\chi\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
where $H^1_\nu(z)$ and  $H^2_\nu(z)$ are Hankel functions. I am interested in solution of the equation 
$$-\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\chi+\Big(\frac{\nu^2-\frac{1}{4}}{r^2}\Big)\chi=i\chi\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$ where $r$ is restricted to positive values. If $z=re^{i\theta}$ in Equation(1), and assuming $\theta$ to be constant one obtains the following upon simplification
$$-\frac{d}{dr^{2}}[\sqrt{r}H_{\nu}(r\exp i\theta)]+\frac{\nu^{2}-\frac{1}{4}}{r^{2}}[\sqrt{r}H_{\nu}(r\exp i\theta)]=\exp2i\theta[\sqrt{r}H_{\nu}(r\exp i\theta)]\ .$$
In the above $H_{\nu}$ can be any of the two Hankel functions. Also for a choice of $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, one obtains Equation(2). Is it alright to conclude that the solutions of the eigenvalue problem posed in Equation(2) are $\sqrt{r}H^1_{\nu}(r\exp i\frac{\pi}{4})$ and $\sqrt{r}H^2_{\nu}(r\exp i\frac{\pi}{4})$? The reason why I doubt this is because a particular paper considers only $\sqrt{r}H^1_{\nu}(r\exp i\frac{\pi}{4})$ as a solution but not $\sqrt{r}H^2_{\nu}(r\exp i\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Thanks.

Comment: They picked up the solution which is convenient for them.  So it depends on your problem.